# Как вложить header в div с thumbnail'ом (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Я совершенно не знаю php, у меня сайт на Wordpress, появилось желание подверстать заголовок поста так, чтобы h1 красиво лежат поверх thumbnail'а. Но для этого мне нужна вложенность, а как это сделать, не знаю.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вложить header в div с thumbnail'ом:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
echo '<div class="single-post-thumbnail clear">';
echo the_post_thumbnail('large-thumb');
echo '</div>';
}
?>
<header class="entry-header">
<?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
</header>
```

Comment: Я думаю правильнее будет наоборот, миниатюру добавить в хедер!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
<div class="single-post-thumbnail clear">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php echo the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
    </header>
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('large-thumb'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```